# Is "Battlefield Earth" good science fiction by Hubbard's standards?

Tags: l-ron-hubbard

[L. Ron Hubbard says](http://battlefieldearth.com/introduction/) that to be "pure," "credible," and "have a point," (all things he clearly values highly) science fiction must be plausible; limited in its possibilities; have to do with material-based sciences; be focused on people over machines; and not incorporate spiritualism, the supernatural, mythology, or similar non-materialistic phenomena or notions.

Does *Battlefield Earth* meet Hubbard's own criteria for science fiction which is not just "pure," but credible and pointed? The story seemed neither plausible nor limited to me, but it's been a very long time since I read the novel and I'm willing to be convinced otherwise by people more familiar with it than I.

Comment: Terrifyingly, by Hubbard's standards *as a sci-fi writer*, it's one of his better efforts.

Comment: I would need to re-read entire *Battlefield Earth* again to answer this. I'll see all'y'all in about 2 years.

Comment: Is the question inclusive of post-Psychlo-blowing-up part?

Comment: @DVK Why wouldn't it be? This is lit.se, so the fact that the historic film only covers part of the novel wouldn't be a reason to ignore the rest of the novel.

Comment: @BESW - mostly because it would take far longer to re-read the whole thing :)